# How do I write a unit test to check for correct behavior under conditions of transient system resource constraints?

Tags: python, unit-testing, docker, virtual-machine, nose

I have a Python 3 application which uses the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module to spread a large, resource intensive scientific calculation over many CPUs in parallel.  There are a couple of steps inside the calculation that require the process to allocate moderately large arrays.  The application works just fine when I run it on my OS X laptop, however, the long term plan is that it will typically be run from inside a docker container, which will in turn run on an [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) EC2 instance or other comparable cloud-based virtual machine--effectively nesting the application within two levels of machine virtualization technology.

I am anticipating that in the future, some other user may attempt to run the application with the virtual machine resources (memory, swap space, etc.) configured to values which have been set a bit too aggressively small.  (There are clear financial incentives to do this, because you tend to pay less for cloud computing services, the fewer resources you use.)

This brings up the possibility, under a tightly constrained resources scenario, that one of the processes could try to allocate memory for an array at a moment when a sufficiently large block of memory is temporarily not available, thereby triggering a Python `MemoryError` exception.

A solution to this problem might look something like the code snippet below: try to allocate the memory, catch the exception if it occurs, then wait a while and try again:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
import os
from warnings import warn

def getHugeArray(n, retry=1, warnuser=5):

    # Don't retry too often
    if retry < 0.1:
        retry = 1
    # Don't send a useless flood of warning messages
    if warnuser < retry:
        warnuser = retry

    success, outarray = False, None
    startwait, lastcount = datetime.datetime.now(), 0
    # Keep re-asking the OS for memory allocation until the OS gives it to us
    while success is False:
        try:
            outarray = np.zeros(n)
            success = True
        except MemoryError:
            time.sleep(retry)
            wait = (datetime.datetime.now()-startwait).total_seconds()
            newcount = int(wait/warnuser)
            if newcount > lastcount:
                msg = 'PID {0}: waiting for memory allocation for {1} seconds'
                warn(msg.format(os.getpid(), wait))
                lastcount = newcount

    return outarray
```

My question: how would I construct a unit test to verify the waiting behavior?  Or is that even possible?  It seems like I would have to write a test which sets itself up by first hogging up most of the memory resources on my system, then waits for a while as the `getHugeArray()` function begins to execute, then releases the resources so that `getHugeArray()` may grab them, and ultimately checks to see if the `getHugeArray()` function comes back with a correct return value.

Is this something that would be better to try to do within an integration testing framework rather than as a unit test?  Or in any case, what is an appropriate tool or test framework that I could use to test my code in this type of situation, and how should I set it up?

Comment: I would wrap the allocation code in a separate function and decorate it with `@retry`, then it will be trivial to test.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

Comment: @Dan Hmmm...not bad.  I was unaware of the retrying module.  It's sort of orthogonal to the kind of answer that I had been expecting (offload the problem of assuring code reliability to a different module rather than trying to test it myself) but I have to admit that it leads to _way_ more succinct code than the way that I was doing it.